# nunchuk.io - "To create new wallets, additional XPUBs from the key are needed."

Tags: wallet, multi-signature, xpub

I'm trying to start using Nunchuk (nunchuk.io), so I created 3 software keys on 3 different devices for my account, and then was able to create a wallet using those 3 keys as signers.
But when I try to create a second wallet the same way with those same 3 keys, I get the following error: "To create new wallets, additional XPUBs from the key are needed."

I don't know what this means, I tried on the PC and phone.

Is there a limitation for using the same keys on multiple wallets?

EDIT: To give a bit more context, one key was created on an Android smartphone, another key on an Android tablet, and the last one on a Windows 11 laptop. The original error is thrown on the Windows 11 laptop. A similar (?) error occurs when trying to do the same on the Android devices: "Run out of cached xpub!"